# Undergraduate Interviewing for Research Assistant Jobs- Tips?

Tags: job-search, interview, research-assistantship

So, after having an interest in pursuing a full time position in research to live and breathe research without class commitments in hopes of building a strong skillset, I decided to pursue job opportunities at research facilities and research heavy academic institutions. After initially getting rejected by HR for open positions, I started "cold e-mailing" PIs at various locations around my general location who advertised open slots on their lab websites. I got a reply from a big shot PI who was interested in my resume and conducts research at a top 10 university...which was ridiculously unexpected. He wanted an interview the day he comes back from a conference.

I've always thought a strong suit of mine was eloquently illustrating passion, and I do believe that was the bulk of my application's success (he mentioned this in his reply, which was a response like 1 hour after I e-mailed him). I'm not lacking confidence in myself, but I am slightly confused and personally believe my background does not warrant a top 10 reply (my university is not even in the top 100, lack of publications, no in depth experience, 1.5 years of research at my uni and 2 REUs at his alma matar for his MS and PhD, and I'm about to only receive an undergraduate degree). That being said, I'm both nervous and excited- this is a dream position. I've never been in this position, and I wanted to ask for advice on what to do during an interview.

How do I not ruin this job? What do most PIs look for? What "studying" should I do in my free time between now and the interview (~1 month)? Any tips?

Comment: Congrats on scoring an interview, you sound really excited and I hope it goes well for you :)

Comment: Related [answer for the person on the other side of the interview](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/1713/11365)

Comment: I had an interview in high school for a summer position I totally messed up because I wasn't familiar enough with the details of their projects. You should be prepared to answer very clearly "what do you want to do with us and why?"

Comment: How was the result though?